# Used ceiling fan not working

Tags: ceiling-fan

Bought a used ceiling fan w 2 pull chains and lights. Seller assures me it was working. Hung it up and wired it fan black and blue to ceiling black, white to white, and both a  green wire from the down rod and a green wire from the fan hanging ball to the ceiling copper wire. Multimeter test shows 120v when red probe is touched to light socket and black probe to housing screw head. Pull chain to light shows 0 when chain is pulled off. Was a ceiling light with a single wall switch. Why is neither the lights or fan coming on?

Comment: The seller assured you the fan worked. Are you 100% he wasn't stretching the truth?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing hot (light socket center) to **ground** (housing screw) and getting 120 volts. How about between light socket center and light socket screw threads? This will test hot to neutral which is where you need the voltage. Assuming this is not near 120 volts, it sounds like your neutral (white) wire is not connected. You should probably take down the fan and test voltage between black and white wires or, better yet, reconnect the old light to test. Assuming this works, reconnect the fan, making sure the get good connections with the wirenuts.

Comment: Ceiling black to white shows 0 on the multimeter. Previous light fixture worked. What happened?

Comment: @SField Do you know how the original light was wired? It's possible that the neutral/white wire in the ceiling is broken and someone used ground in place of neutral. This will work (provided the breaker is not GFCI) but is not legal and is potentially very dangerous! Otherwise, check the ceiling to see if there was a wirenut connecting the white wire to another; it may have come loose. Somehow, the neural is no longer working.